# QTP - lbound() and ubound()

Tags: arrays, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm having some troubles doing something easy: checking the most recent date in an array.
 I create an array of webelements. There are some dates in this array in "fixed" places and I want to take the most recent of them. 
This is what I'm doing:

```
    Set cc = Description.Create
    cc("micclass").value="WebElement"
    cc("name").value="arrow_down"
    Set collcc=Browser("Br").Page("Page").ChildObjects(cc)

    For i=lbound(collcc)  to ubound(collcc)
        Msgbox collcc(x).getroproperty("innertext")
        x =x +9
    Next
```

The problem is that the script stops at the beginning of the for, saying that there is a "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment ubound" (and the same happens with lbound. 
What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just from memory, but i think `ChildObjects` does not return an array. Try with

```
for i = 0 to collcc.Count - 1
    ....
next
```

Comment: it returns a collection of objects... I feel so stupid right now xD
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Child object is the collection of objects so you needs to loop through "for each " Snippet given below

```
for each col in collcc
 Msgbox col.getroproperty("innertext")
Next
```

Thanks
Sai